# How to split a list into two lists and find the length of them?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to find the length of odd and even list after splitting them..

I tried to create size function and call it inside split but it does not work.

```
size([],0).
size([_|T],N):-size(T,N1),N is N1+1.

split([],[],[]).
split([X|L],[X|L1],L2):-
   X mod 2 =:=0,
   split(L,L1,L2),
split([X|L],L1,[X|L2]):-
   split(L,L1,L2).

?- split([1,2,4,6,7,8,9,11],X,Y).
X = [2, 4, 6, 8],
Y = [1, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added, how you created this output

Comment: @HendrikEvert: your edits are not helpful. Instead, tell in a comment or answer what you spotted.

Comment: Why no just run this (multi-predicate) goal at the toplevel: `split([1,2,4,6,7,8,9,11],X,Y), size(X,LenX), size(Y,LenY)`? AFTER having fixed the second clause of `split`, replacing the final `,` by a `.`. Try it in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/).

Comment: there is a comma add the end of the clause of the second line that starts with 'split'. Thus, the code wont work when its copy pasted. Therefore I do not see a reason to reject my edit, but if you cared to explain I would be happy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a length parameter for each list as follows:

```
size([],0).
size([_|T],N):-size(T,N1),N is N1+1.

split([],[],[], 0, 0).
split([X|L],[X|L1],L2, A, B) :- 
   X mod 2 =:=0, 
   split(L,L1,L2, A1, B), 
   size([X|L1], A), 
   size(L2, B), 
   A is A1+1.
split([X|L],L1,[X|L2], A, B) :- 
   split(L,L1,L2, A, B1), 
   size(L1, A), 
   size([X|L2], B), 
   B is B1+1.
```

Calling

```
split([1,2,4,6,7,8,9,11, 13], X, Y, LenX, LenY).
```

will return:

```
X = [2, 4, 6, 8],
Y = [1, 7, 9, 11, 13],
LenX = 4,
LenY = 5
```

Comment: It shows that there is an error, I couldn't find where: Warning: c:/users/user/documents/prolog/assignment_1.pl:5:
        Singleton variables: [LenX,LenY]

Comment: @NANA There are variables in the second clause of `split/5` which are never used elsewhere, hence "singletons": `split([X|L],[X|L1],L2, LenX, LenY) :- `. But trying in it [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) shows some problem with the code.

Comment: sorry i have made a mistake when editing my answer, i have it fixed now and it works for me

Comment: @HendrikEvert Thank you! it works for me now!! I'm new in prolog.

Comment: ```?- split([1,2],E,O,EL,OL).
E = [2],
O = [1],
EL = OL, OL = 1 ```  there is only one small error If number of odd=even, the lenght of even = the variable of odd.

Comment: when the lengths of both lists are the same, prolog will output something like you just posted: ```EL = OL, OL = 1``` This is completely normal and as far as I know can't be avoided. It means that EL holds the same value as OL, which is 1.

Comment: @HendrikEvert Ok! Thanks again.